# Brackets, braces and no-boundary variables conflicting in theorem environment

Tags: environments, theorems, xparse

I'm making a theorem called exercise which I want to be able to be defined in the following ways:

```
\begin{exercise} ...           % Regular exercise with numbering from other exercises
\begin{exercise}[alt] ...      % Regular exercise with alternate name
\begin{exercise}{num} ...      % Exercise with special numbering
\begin{exercise}{num}[alt] ... % Exercise with special name and numbering
```

Here's what I have currently, scrounged from around this site:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{innerexercise}{Exercise}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{exercise}[1]
{
\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{\@ifmtarg{#1}{}{\renewcommand\theinnerexercise{#1}}}
\innerexercise
}
{\endinnerexercise}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

However, the issue is that when I don't want to renumber the exercise, the left bracket in the alternate name gets counted as the input. Instead of the first thing in the picture, I get the second:
[image]
Now I could always add the empty brackets such as `\begin{exercise}{}[alt]`, but I'd like to preserve the ability to simply write `\begin{exercise}[alt]`, as this is something I use constantly.

So is there a way to cut out the interpretation of the next character as an input? Thanks!

PS This also breaks if I do `\begin{exercise} Text of exercise`, as it outputs "Exercise T. ext of exercise", which is not what I want for the same reason.

PPS I think that this has to do in part with the fact that my input is mandatory. If I make it optional, I would be fine if I had to label the argument, for example `\begin{exercise}[num=3.14,alt-name="Title"]`.

Comment: `xparse`'s `\IfNoValueTF` doesn't work with `\newcommand` (or `\newenvironment`) it's an entirely different mechanism

Comment: I'm new to both of these things (they showed up in searches and almost do what I want but not quite), any help would be appreciated!

Comment: With “alternate name” do you mean that you want to substitute “Exercise” with the alternate name?

Comment: @egreg As shown in the top half of the image, I want the alternate name to go in parentheses, like the theorem environment does already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a different delimiter for the further optional argument, here `(...)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed after 2020-10-01

\newtheorem{innerexercise}{Exercise}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{d()}
 {%
  \IfValueT{#1}{\renewcommand{\theinnerexercise}{#1}\addtocounter{innerexercise}{-1}}%
  \innerexercise
 }
 {\endinnerexercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
Regular exercise with numbering from other exercises
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[alt]
Regular exercise with alternate name
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}(num)
Exercise with special numbering
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}(num)[alt]
Exercise with special name and numbering
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
Regular exercise with numbering from other exercises
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, multiple optional arguments are a nuisance, because it's always difficult to remember their relative position and `[alt](num)` would definitely fail.

Here's a version with a key-value syntax. More complex to define, handier to use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed after 2020-10-01

\newtheorem{innerexercise}{Exercise}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{O{}}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { gintz/exercise } { #1 }
  \gintz_exercise_setup:
 }
 {\endinnerexercise}

% the allowed keys
\keys_define:nn { gintz/exercise }
 {
  num .tl_set:N = \l__gintz_exercise_num_tl,
  alt .tl_set:N = \l__gintz_exercise_alt_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \gintz_exercise_setup:
 {
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l__gintz_exercise_num_tl
   {
    \renewcommand{\theinnerexercise}{\l__gintz_exercise_num_tl}
    \addtocounter{innerexercise}{-1}
   }
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l__gintz_exercise_alt_tl
   {
    \innerexercise
   }
   {
    \innerexercise[\l__gintz_exercise_alt_tl]
   } 
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
Regular exercise with numbering from other exercises
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[alt=alt]
Regular exercise with alternate name
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[num=num]
Exercise with special numbering
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[alt=alt,num=num]
Exercise with special name and numbering
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
Regular exercise with numbering from other exercises
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! The key-value structure (once implemented like this, which worked great) is super easy and intuitive, thanks!